# keystone build command failed

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

These are my dependencies:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@keystone-next/auth": "^14.0.0",
  "@keystone-next/keystone": "^9.3.0",
  "@keystone-next/admin-ui": "^8.0.1",
  "@keystone-next/cloudinary": "^2.0.9",
  "@keystone-next/fields": "^4.1.1",
  "@keystone-next/types": "^12.0.0",
  "@keystonejs/server-side-graphql-client": "^1.1.2",
  "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.0",
  "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30001174",
  "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
  "next": "^10.0.5",
  "nodemailer": "^6.4.17",
  "react": "^16.14.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
  "stripe": "^8.130.0",
  "typescript": "^4.4.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.9.0",
  "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.9.0",
  "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
  "eslint": "^7.14.0",
  "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
  "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^12.0.0",
  "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
  "eslint-config-wesbos": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
  "eslint-plugin-html": "^6.1.1",
  "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
  "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
  "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
  "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
  "prettier": "^2.2.1"
},
"engines": {
  "node": ">=14.0.0"
}
```

And this is the error when I run `yarn build`:

```
$ yarn build
yarn run v1.22.10
$ keystone-next build
 Building Keystone
✨ Generating graphQL schema
(node:12244) [DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
✨ Generating Admin UI code
✨ Building Admin UI
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db
(node:12244) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package at F:\course\practies\Apps\ecommerce\Advanced-React\sick-fits\backend\node_modules\@keystone-next\admin-ui\node_modules\postcss\package.json.
Update this package.json to use a subpath pattern like "./*".
info  - Using external babel configuration from F:\course\practies\Apps\ecommerce\Advanced-React\sick-fits\backend\package.json
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
Failed to compile.

ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '........keystone' in 'F:\course\practies\Apps\ecommerce\Advanced-React\sick-fits\backend\.keystone\admin\pages\api'

Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
    at F:\course\practies\Apps\ecommerce\Advanced-React\sick-                
    fits\backend\node_modules\@keystone-next\admin-ui\node_modules\next\build\index.ts:495:13
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at F:\course\practies\Apps\ecommerce\Advanced-React\sick- 
    fits\backend\node_modules\@keystone-next\admin-ui\node_modules\next\build\tracer.ts:22:32
    at Object.buildAdminUI (F:\course\practies\Apps\ecommerce\Advanced-React\sick- 
     fits\backend\node_modules\@keystone-next\admin-ui\system\dist\admin-ui.cjs.dev.js:474:3)
    at Object.build (F:\course\practies\Apps\ecommerce\Advanced-React\sick- 
    fits\backend\node_modules\@keystone-next\keystone\scripts\dist\keystone.cjs.dev.js:465:3)
    error Command failed with exit code 1.
    info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Or are you still seeing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, hope it helps:

1. Delete node_modules folder
2. Delete package-lock.json
3. Change package.json engines to specify a specific node version.
   (Note: When deploying to backend, the host may have a later version of node ex: digital ocean might be something like 16.6.7 - so removing the ">=" may help here)

   ```
   "engines": {
           "node": "14.7.0"
   },
   ```
4. `yarn build` or `npm run build` or if you are auto building on commits then commit the changes.